# setOnClickListener in simple Android does not work

Tags: java, android

I try to learn JAVA and I try to write an app for Android. My Code is simple and often I've seen code like this. But when I push the second time a button, the message does not return. The first time it works. What is my error?

```
package com.test.helloworld;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import android.widget.Toast;

public class HelloWorldApp extends Activity {

    private Button closeButton;
    private Button buttonAnswer1; 

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        buttonAnswer1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        closeButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonEnde);

        buttonAnswer1.setFocusable(false);
        closeButton.setFocusable(false);


        buttonAnswer1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                setContentView(R.layout.main);          
                showToastMessage("1");

            }
        });

        closeButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                setContentView(R.layout.main);          
                showToastMessage("2");
            }
        });         
    }  

    private void showToastMessage(String msg){

        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);

        toast.show();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Don't call the `setContentView` method inside the click listener:

```
buttonAnswer1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        showToastMessage("1");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

In your `onClick` functions, you are replacing the entire content view, which will replace the existing button objects with new instances. These new instances no longer have any OnClickListeners.

There is no reason to replace the content view in this case, so the solution is to eliminate those calls from the `onClick` functions. But if for some reason you needed to replace the content view, then you would need to go through the entire process of finding the new buttons and calling `setOnClickListener` for each.